# change and send data on multiple url with dropdown select doesn't refresh

Tags: jquery, select, refresh, href

i decided to send selected data from a dropdown through url to several link on my page which open different fancybox. But it work only once.

It open the fancybox sending the right data but when i close the fancybox  (which mean it doesn't refresh my page just the one of the fancybox) and i change the value of my dropdown and reopen my fancybox the value sent didn't change and i'm stuck with the first send value.

could you help me please and explain to me why it doesn't work, i'm new to jquery, thanks.

```
$the_event = mysql_query("SELECT `event_id`, `name` FROM `event` ORDER BY event_id ASC");
```

dropdown menu with the evenement

```
 echo '<select name="<?php$the_event?>" style="width: 150px">';
while( list($event_id, $event_name) = mysql_fetch_row($the_event) )
{

echo '<option value="'.$event_id.'">'.$event_name.'</option>';

}

echo '</select>';

?>
</div>
```

menu galery of the different sport of the event that open different statistic of each sport in a fancybox

```
<nav>

<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery_hurdling" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/H1.php" data-fancybox-group="gallery_hurdling"  tabindex="1" title="hurdling" alt="sport 1"   ><img src="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/css/hurdling.png" alt="sport 1"  /></a>

<div class="hidden">

<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery_hurdling" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/H2.php" data-fancybox-group="gallery_hurdling" title="hurdling"  ></a>

</div>

<a class="fancybox"  data-fancybox-type="iframe"  data-fancybox-group="gallery_wattball" href="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/template-statistics_details2.php"  tabindex="2" title="wattball" alt="sport 2"   ><img src="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/css/wattball.png" alt="sport 2"  />         </a>

<div class="hidden">

<a class="fancybox"  data-fancybox-type="iframe"  data-fancybox-group="gallery_wattball" href="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/template-statistics_details1.php" title="wattball"  > </a>

<a class="fancybox"   data-fancybox-type="iframe"  data-fancybox-group="gallery_wattball" href="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/template-statistics_details3.php"  title="wattball"  ></a>

</div>

</nav>
```

function that obtain the value of the selected item in the dropdown and put it at the end of the href with "?chosen="  of every stat page .
so that they can get the event and open the different statistic of the selected event

```
Query(function($) {

 $("select").change(function () 
 {

     var str = "";

     $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {

          str += $(this).val() + " ";   

          $("a").attr('href', function(i, href) {

                var newUrl =  $(this).attr('href')+'?chosen='+str;

                $(this).attr('href',newUrl);

                 });
           });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("a").attr('href',..` will change every `<a>` in page. Need more details as to what you expect. Provide some html in question and refrence the html with further details of what you expect code to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you change the href attribute with JQuery, that is the new HREF.  The second time that you select an option, the href has the querystring appended to it.  For example

```
 <a class="fancybox"   data-fancybox-type="iframe"  data-fancybox-group="gallery_wattball" href="http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/template-statistics_details3.php"  title="wattball"  ></a>
```

Has an href of http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/template-statistics_details3.php.

The first time you select something it would become http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/template-statistics_details3.php?chosen=somevalue.

The next time you select something it would become

http://www.wattsports.co.uk/wp-content/themes/canvas/template-statistics_details3.php?chosen=somevalue?chosen=SomeOtherValue

You need a way to store the original href, or add code to remove the chosen=somevalue querystring before adding a new querystring.

Comment: thanks a lot .i'm going to put the data after .php in the url to replace the automatiquelly the data. I don't know why id didn't think of that.